# How do I add org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs to gitignore?

Tags: eclipse, git, gitignore

What regex do I use to add `org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs` to my `.gitignore`, so that it ignores all occurrences of this file?

Adding each occurrence separately or any regex like `//org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs` or `/./org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs` does not seem to help.

Comment: I added the entries and gave git status command. Should .gitignore be committed too?

Comment: did you just try `org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs`?

Comment: Yes. I did. But did not succeed.

Comment: please include the output of `git status`.  
`.gitignore` only affects untracked files, if you have already added the file to the repo, you need to untrack it first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs` will work. However, I'm guessing that you committed the files to your repository already.  .gitignore will not ignore files that have already been committed.  So, you need to:

1. remove all `org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs` files from the repo
2. add line to gitignore
3. commit gitignore

And all of your prefs files will be ignored afterwards.